# cross validation and text classification for imbalanced data

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, svm, pipeline, cross-validation

I am new to NLP and I am trying to build a text classifier but my data is currently imbalanced.The highest category having as much as 280 entries while the lowest as much as 30.
I am trying to use cross validation technique for the current data, but after looking for days now i am unable to implement it.It looks pretty straightforward but I am still unable  to implement it. Here is my code

```
y = resample.Subsystem
X = resample['new description']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
X_train_counts.shape
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
X_train_tfidf.shape
#SVM
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
text_clf_svm = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')),('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),('clf-svm', SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, n_iter=5, random_state=42)),])
text_clf_svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
predicted_svm = text_clf_svm.predict(X_test)
print('The best accuracy is : ',np.mean(predicted_svm == y_test))
```

I have done some gridsearch and Stemmer further but right now I would work on cross validation on this code.I have cleaned the data pretty well but i am stil getting an accuracy of 60%
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=None)
# X is the feature set and y is the target
from sklearn.model_selection import RepeatedKFold 
kf = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=20, n_repeats=10, random_state=None) 

for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
  #print("Train:", train_index, "Validation:",test_index)
  X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index] 
  y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do oversampling or under sampling. As the data is highly imbalanced, There is more bias towards the class with more data points. After the over/under sampling the bias will be very less and accuracy will up.

Else instead of SVM you can use MLP. It gives good results even with unbalanced data.

Comment: I oversampled the data but that's something i would like to avoid because thats just duplicating the data, i don't learn anything from it

Comment: try for under sampling but your data points are too less, still you can give a try.
Does oversampling increased the accuracy ?

Comment: it did, but again, i would like to avoid it, its not really a good method i feel